# Find an anti-example of Clairaut's theorem

Tags: calculus, partial-derivative

Here is a quote from Calculus: Early Transcendentals written by James Stewart

> Clairaut’s Theorem：Suppose $f$ is defined on a disk $D$ that contains the point $(a, b)$. If the functions $f_{xy}$ and $f_{yx}$ are both continuous on $D$, then $f_{xy} = f_{yx}$

Where
$$f_{xy} \equiv \frac{\partial}{\partial y} \left( \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} \right)$$

I don't know how to compose a function that $f_{xy}$ or $f_{yx}$ are **not** continuous on $(a, b)$. Can you give me an example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For example take
$$
f(x,y)= xy\frac{x^2-y^2}{x^2+y^2} \quad ((x,y)\not=(0,0)), \quad \quad f(0,0)=0.
$$
Here $f_x$ and $f_y$ both exist and are even continuous on $\mathbb{R}^2$, and
$$
f_{xy}(0,0)=-1,\quad f_{yx}(0,0)=1.
$$
The continuity of $f_x$ and $f_y$ in $(0,0)$ is a bit tricky, but it is easy to show that $f_x(0,y)=-y$ for all $y$ and $f_y(x,0)=x$ for all $x$.

Edit: You can see directly that $f_{xy}$ and $f_{yx}$ are not continuous in $(0,0)$. You have calculated
$$
f_{xy}(x,y)=f_{yx}(x,y)=\frac{x^6+9x^4y^2-9x^2y^4-y^6}{(x^2+y^2)^3} \quad ((x,y) \not= (0,0)).
$$
Inserting $(1/n,1/n)$ leads to $f_{xy}(1/n,1/n)= 0 \to 0$ $(n \to \infty)$. Inserting $(1/n,0)$ leads to $f_{xy}(1/n,0)= 1 \to 1$ $(n \to \infty)$. Thus $\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)} f_{xy}(x,y)$ does not exist.

Comment: I try to calculate $f_{xy}$ and $f_{yx}$. They are the same.
$$
f_{xy} = \frac{x^2 - y^2}{x^2 + y^2} + 8xyf \frac{x^2 + y^2}{(x^2 + y^2)^3} = \frac{x^6 + 9x^4y^2 -9x^2y^4 - y^6}{(x^2 + y^2)^3} = f_{yx}
$$

Comment: Of course they are the same on $\mathbb{R}^2 \setminus \{(0,0)\}$ according to Clairaut's Theorem. But $f_{xy}(0,0)$ and $f_{yx}(0,0)$ are different and have to be calculated by the definition of partial derivatives. This shows that  $f_{xy}$ and  $f_{yx}$ cannot both be continuous in an neighborhood of $(0,0)$.

Comment: I see. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Just pick any function which isn't continuous and integrate it twice.

For example, let $D=(-1,1)\times (-1,1)$. Consider
$$g(x,y)=\operatorname{sgn}(x)\operatorname{sgn}(y)$$
Which is not continuous on $D$. Now let
$$f(x,y)=\int_0^y\int_0^x g(x',y')\mathrm dx'\mathrm dy' \\ =\int_0^y\int_0^x \operatorname{sgn}(x')\operatorname{sgn}(y')\mathrm dx'\mathrm dy' \\ =\int_0^y|x|\operatorname{sgn}(y')\mathrm dy' \\ =|xy|$$

Note that $f$ **is** continuous on $D$.

Comment: I should add: $\operatorname{sgn}(x)=|x|/x$ and $\operatorname{sgn}(0)=0$ is the sign function.

Comment: How are $f_{xy}$ and $f_{yx}$ defined on a neighborhood of the origin?

Comment: @TedShifrin That wasn't stated as a requirement.

Comment: The hypothesis was “$f_{xy}$ and $f_{yx}$ are both continuous on the disk $D$,” so I believe you are in error.

Comment: @TedShifrin As I understand, Clairaut's theorem says $\partial_{xy}f,\partial_{yx}f$ both continuous implies they are equal. So of course we will use an example where they aren't continuous.

Comment: Yes, OK, I responded to the wrong issue. You're claiming the equality of $f_{xy}(0)$ and $f_{yx}(0)$ fails to hold because neither is defined? Perhaps you win on a logical technicality, but I don't think you're enhancing the OP's understanding of the theorem.

Comment: @TedShifrin Admittedly, I suppose I could have chosen a better example.